# How can I get the type name to log along with the method name with a Castle interceptor?

Tags: castle-windsor, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

Is there a way I can get the type that method belongs to to log with a [Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_Project) interceptor?

Comment: I guess I should have looked closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string targetTypeName = invocation.TargetType.FullName;
```